# Producing map of higher level regions using postal codes in SAS only?

Tags: postal-code, australia, sas

I have a map of Australian postal codes (technically a postal code shapefile downloaded from the Australian Bureau of Statistics (ABS) Web Site) and I want to use this map to construct a higher level map using proc gmap in SAS.

For example, a number of postal regions will form a larger region and I only want to show this larger region.

Is this possible?

The reason I need to do this is that the ABS does not provide a map for this higher level region and so I need to do this myself.

Of course, this is possible in MapInfo, but I want to do it in SAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PROC GMAP can do this then I would expect the operation to have a name of something like Dissolve, which in other GIS packages merges polygons based on a common attribute values.

My Google searches did not find one so I think you should ask SAS direct.